# Como asignar el valor de textbox a una variable de javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tengo mi cuadro de texto en `html`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="200px" Width="1000px" BackColor=""></asp:TextBox>
```

y quiero asignar el valor a una variable que tengo en `Javascript`:

```
var nombre1 =
```

Comment: eso se hace con `var nombre 1 = document.getElementById('id_de_texto').val;` asi es como se le asigna en caso de que el cuadro de texto tenga un id, si es por nombre de clase es `var nombre 1 = document.getElementByClassName('class_de_texto').val;`

Comment: bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te invito a que vayas por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla :D

Answer (score 1):

Hola con jquery es facil

```
<input type=" text" id="algo "/> 

var algo = $(selector).val();
```

espero te funcione

saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Tengan en cuenta que los IDs que genera WebForms en el lado del cliente tiene una forma "rara", esto es para mantener todos los IDs únicos, por lo tanto:

```
var nombre1 = $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').val();
```

Comment: Exacto eso iba a decir, lo que le recomiendan le dará error puesto que si le puso de id **mytxt** en el navegador aparecerá con un id distinto algo así como **Content_mytxt**, para ello tiene que o bien inspeccionar el navegador y ver como esta el id o de plano hacer lo que dices @fredyfx

Answer (score 0):

Si haces usos tanto de un

```
<input id="id_etiqueta"> o <textarea id="id_etiqueta">
```

puedes capturar el valor con

```
var nombre1 = document.getElementById("id_etiqueta").value;
```

o asignar el valor

```
document.getElementById("id_etiqueta").value = "Valor Nuevo";
```