# como convertir una cadena de Base64 a imagen JPEG en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un cuadro de TextBox en mi html donde esta la cadena de base64 pero quiero convertir esta cadena en imagen y así poder aguardarla localmente pero quiero hacer este proceso en javascript.

Comment: bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te invito a que vayas por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla :D  Por cierto, revisa la respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/146574/822 a tu anterior pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Podrías guardarlo en el `localStorage` de javascript.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon un ejemplo de lo que has hecho hasta ahora y en que tienes duda o donde te has trabado.

Comment: @Aprendiendox te invito a leer [mcve] para que sea mejor recibida la pregunta